# How to prevent the iPad keyboard going dead when submitting a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, ipad, submit

I'm having a strange issue:

I have a search from, which when I'm submitting on iPad will not hide the keyboard but stall it until the search results are being loaded.

So as soon as I hit enter on the keyboard, the iPad goes dead with open keyboard and only when the search is done, the keyboard hides and the results start apprearing.

Right now my script is listening to `change` events to trigger functions, such as the search form in question, which probably is the problem.

**Question:**
Is there a one-code-fits-all-devices approach to trigger a form submit, so my keyboard first disappears and then the search starts?

Thanks for inputs!

**EDIT:**
My button:

```
  <input type="text" value="" id="searchField" data-type="search" placeholder="Suche" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c">
```

My script handling it:

```
$('#searchField').keypress(function(e){
     if(e.which == 13){

        $('#searchField').trigger('blur');
        loadMulti( "yes" );
        return false;
        }
    });
```

Hm. I guess the whole thing.... isn't constructed very nice.

Comment: Does your change event handler return a boolean value or have any other side-effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know the ipad keyboard dissapears automatically on blur. There is no code posted but my guess is that your script blurs after the query is finished.

Comment: so I would have to bind to `blur` on iPad? mh.

Comment: That depends. If the results are ajax loaded (like Google) while typing you should bind to keyup, because then you dont want your keyboard to dissapear.

Comment: a little bit of both, the results are AJAX loaded, but the whole page is and I'm not updating results on keyup. If I add an autocomplete script, I will want to have the keyboard open, but for plain-vanilla form submits, I need it be closed.

Comment: Is the input nested in a <form> element? Hitting enter/return in a nested text input automatically submits the form thus blurs the input (and removes the keyboard), guess that's not your case? The only way to hide the keyboard is blur the input. So if it is not nested you Should additionally trigger blur on hitting enter/return key

Comment: Good idea, but it doesn't work. It's a text input, I'm pasting the code above.

Comment: Just tested your script handling key 13, but that actually worked on my ipad!

Comment: I guess it was my loadMultiple function, which triggered right away and prevented the keyboard from hiding. I had my trigger('blur') inside this function along with showing a loading spinner but neither one appeared, I guess also "blocked" by my function call...

Answer (score 1):

Good ol `setTimout` saves the day:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
     loadMulti( "yes" );
     },10);
```

It seems triggering an Ajax form submit really stalls the whole page, because I had my trigger for blur as well as my loading spinner activated from inside `loadMulti`, which fires my Ajax form submit. Neither one showed up, so I eventually thought why not set a timeout for everything to setup, the keyboard to hide and THEN fire the function.

Works... even with 5ms.